# Pass Data into a VSTO Excel Workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I've got an VSTO Excel Workbook project that I'm using to gather information from a user.  This workbook is being launched from inside of a host application, but I need to pass some parameters to the workbook before opening it so it knows what to display and how to display it.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I did not get ur Question !! what you want to display when it will open..tell us in brief..i think i can help u ..do u want to hide or hsow columns on the startUP ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of passing data to a workbook which personally I don't really like, but maybe it can suit you. Basically, you set values for specific cells in the workbook, and then process those values in Excel's event handler:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
                var sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
                var range = sheet.Range["A1"];
                range.Value2 = "some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use database or isolated storage for to exchange data between your host and hostee.