# Pass parameters to VSTO-enabled Excel Spreadsheet on server

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I created an Excel 2010 Workbook project with to customize some ribbon extensions. It uses a webservice to read in data to pre-populate the form. My question is, how can I pass in some parameters, for example a record ID, to the workbook when it is requested from the server?

I think my scenario is similar to this question, which was never answered: [Pass Data into a VSTO Excel Workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046657/pass-data-into-a-vsto-excel-workbook)

Comment: I'm a little confused about what's happening. There's a VSTO-enabled workbook on a server, with some form that somehow opens when the workbook opens, and then you want to pass in, say, an ID to the form so the form can load the appropriate data? And you get that ID from a webservice?

Also, what was lacking in the answer given in the question you linked to?

Comment: Can you clarify: is the Workbook running on the server (bad idea)? And can you explain the workflow involving a server request? Why is the server making a request, instead of the VSTO add-in calling a service passing in the ID?

Comment: @Jason Denizac, did you find the answer? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I never figured it out. The desire was to have the user download the workbook from a server with some values pre-filled out. The workbook would include an extension which would let the user modify the values and submit the data back to the server via a REST API. We ended up implementing the form as a web page, rather than excel for maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of passing data to a workbook which personally I don't really like, but maybe it can suit you. Basically, you set values for specific cells in the workbook, and then process those values in Excel's event handler:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
                var sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
                var range = sheet.Range["A1"];
                range.Value2 = "some value";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isn't exactly what I was going for - I was looking for a way to pass data into a workbook dynamically. Ultimately I think I was approaching Excel extensions the wrong way - I wanted to distribute them with the workbook, and our domain security policy didn't like that. See my comment on the original question - we ended up not using Excel.